# Can Mathematica create multi-page PDF files?

Tags: pdf, wolfram-mathematica

When one imports a multi-page pdf file (the file I have in mind contains images of artwork, one per page) into Mathematica 8.0.1 by

> book = Import["simple.pdf"]

Mathematica returns a list of graphics objects, one for each page. I have some manipulations I perform on each page, and then want to save the changed pages back into a single PDF file

> Export["DistortedSimple.pdf", distortedbook]

the resulting file has all of the images on a single page. Is there a convenient way to export a list of images to PDF, one per page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible with `Export`, no matter how much I play with the [`Pages`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/PDF.html) element (apart from the notebook-based solutions given by others).

An alternative is to [install pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk/) (a relatively small command line tool that we'll use to assemble the pages), and use the following Mathematica function:

```
exportMultipagePDF[name_String, g_List, options___] :=
  Module[
    {fileNames, quote},
    quote[s_] := "\"" <> s <> "\"";
    fileNames = 
      Table[
        FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "mmapage" <> IntegerString[i] <> ".pdf"}],
        {i, Length[g]}
      ];
    Check[
      Export[#1, #2, "PDF", options] & @@@ Thread[{fileNames, g}], 
      Return[$Failed]
    ];
    If[
      Run["pdftk", Sequence @@ (quote /@ fileNames), "cat output", name] =!= 0,
      Return[$Failed]
    ];
    DeleteFile /@ fileNames;
  ]
```

On Windows I needed to quote the file names before passing them to PDFtk.  I don't know about other platforms, hopefully it won't cause any trouble.

Try it with

```
exportMultipagePDF["test.pdf", Table[Graphics[{Hue[x], Disk[]}], {x, 0, 1, .2}]]
```

Comment: Philosophically, I like this approach best, but it's returning $Failed (from the Run command, which itself is returning 32512). I'm on Mac OS X 10.6...

Comment: @Kevin, does it create the PDF anyway?  Did you install pdftk, and can you run it from the command line?

Comment: @Kevin Define `printCommand[s___String] := (Print@StringJoin@Riffle[{s}, " "]; 0)` and replace `Run` in my code with `printCommand` (no other change needed).  This will print the precise command used to call `pdftk`, which then you can debug.  One possibility is that the command line is too long (too many pages), which we can try to fix by not prepending the full temp directory to every file name, but instead doing the processing inside the temp directory.  Or maybe OS X doesn't like/need quotation marks?

Comment: If I cut-and-paste the output pf printCommand into a terminal, the desired pdf file is created (your 6 page test file, anyway; works both with and without quote marks). But cut-and-paste into a Run command, and no file is created and 32512 is returned.

Comment: @Kevin I have no idea why ... it works on Windows.  I'll try on Linux when I get the chance.  There are no Macs here ...

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant I think 32512 means 'command not found', so from Mathematica's point of view pdftk is not in the path ...

Comment: Changing "pdftk" to "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/pdftk", which is where pdftk chose to install itself, works! I'm still not entirely clear on why it works from any directory on the command line, but with Run one needs the complete path, but it works. Thanks, Szabolcs.

Answer (score 5):

(Hi Kevin!)

I just evaluated:

```
Print[ExampleData[#]] & /@ Take[ExampleData["TestImage"], 6]

Export["Desktop/Kevin.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[]]
```

using V8.0.1 for OS X, and the resulting PDF was split into four pages.  So I think you best approach is to (programmatically) create a notebook of your modified images, and export that notebook.

Comment: Hello Brett, been a long time! This gets it into a file, but the resulting file is not really suitable for in-class (nor on-kindle) display. I need more page-by-page control...

Comment: @Sjoerd I just haven't made 8.0.4 the version of Mathematica in my dock yet.

Answer (score 3):

Try saving the notebook as PDF rather than Exporting the set of cells as a PDF.

EDIT:

To ensure you have your page breaks where you want, set Screen Environment to Printing (you can do this via a [menu command](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/ScreenEnvironment.html) or [programmatically](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScreenStyleEnvironment.html)), and insert page breaks using the [relevant menu command](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/PageBreak.html). This [guide page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PageLayoutAndPrintingControl.html) might be helpful.

From your comment, it sounds like you need to set the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) option for the transformed image to ensure it is the size you want when displaying onscreen.

Comment: This works, but isn't wholly satisfactory. The images are small, so I lose control of pagination (I'd like the new image and the old image to be on the same page number, for each comparison). Also, when viewing the pdf in full-screen, the image isn't scaled to the screen (as it is in the original file), but rather the page is. This leaves the distorted image tiny.

Comment: @KevinO'Bryant you can fix these things by inserting page breaks where you want them and scaling the graphics appropriately. I'll add some more detail to my answer to elaborate.

Comment: One thing I can't check (not near a Mathematica installation just now) is whether the programmatic `NotebookSave` command works for saving as PDF. http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookSave.html